# Use of setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) with pre Lollipop Circular Reveal library

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, circularreveal

I'm working on a project in which I want to use the Circular Reveal effect as per the Material Design. Project has minSDK = 11, so for compatibility with pre-Lollipop devices, I'm using this library https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal

I've a fragment with a FloatingActionButton that, when tapped, will transform itself in the CardView, like described here [FAB transformations](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-transitions).

Once the card is revealed it has a button to revert the animation, re-transforming the card into the FAB. Now my problem is this: let's say that a user tap the FAB and the CardView is revealed. Now the user rotate his device, so the activity resets the fragment. What I want to achieve is the card stay visible and revealed, while the FAB should be disabled and invisible. The problem is that if I simply use `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` on my FAB it doesn't work (note that if I use `getVisibility()` on it just after setting it invisible, it correctly returns me the value 4 == View.INVISIBLE, but the fab is still visible). I've to wrap the `setVisibility(...)` call inside a `postDelayed()` with at least 50-100 ms of delay to make the fab invisible.

So my question is: am I doing things right or there's a better way to accomplish what I want (because it seems very ugly to me)?

Here's some code. This is my XML layout of the fragment:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_expanded_height"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="70dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarPopupTheme"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    ...
    <io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/my_fragment" />
    </io.codetail.widget.RevealFrameLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/my_appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|left|start" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

This is the XML layout of the included CardView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        ...
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="end">
            <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:text="Ok" />
            <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Cancel" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And this is the code of my Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String CARD_OPEN_TAG = "CARD_OPEN_TAG";

    public static MyFragment newInstance(){
        return new MyFragment();
    }

    private int cardOpen;
    private FloatingActionButton fabAddPublication;
    private CardView card;
    private Button cardCancel;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_magazines, container, false);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layout);

        ...

        // Initialize view status
        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            cardOpen = savedInstanceState.getInt(CARD_OPEN_TAG);
        } else {
            cardOpen = -1;
        }

        ...

        // Get FAB reference
        fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab_id);
        // Get card reference
        card = (CardView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.card_id);
        editorPublication.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // Using this event because I need my card to be measured to move correctly fab at his center
                if (cardOpen != -1){
                    // Move FAB to center of card
                    fab.setTranslationX(coordX); // WORKS
                    fab.setTranslationY(coordY); // WORKS
                    // fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) -> DOESN'T WORK, fab remain visible on top and at center of my card
                    // Ugly workaround
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // Hide FAB
                            fab.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    }, 50); // Sometimes fails: if device/emulator use too much time to "rotate" screen, fab stay visible
                    // Remove listener
                    ViewTreeObserver obs = card.getViewTreeObserver();
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                        obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                    else obs.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                }
            }
        });
        if (editorOpen != -1){
            fab.setEnabled(false); // WORKS
            card.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // WORKS
        }
        // Get editors buttons reference
        cardCancel = (Button) card.findViewById(R.id.card_cancel_id);
        // Set FAB listener
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Explode FAB
                explodeFab(fab, card); // This method trigger the reveal animation
                cardOpen = card.getId();
            }
        });
        // Set editors button listeners
        cardCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Implode FAB
                implodeFAB(fab, card); // This card reverts the reveal animation
        cardOpen = -1;
            }
        });

        ...

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        ...
        outState.putInt(CARD_OPEN_TAG, cardOpen);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that what you're doing is correct and here's why:

1.

That circular reveal library you're using is incompatible with hardware acceleration on Android 11 to 17 (3.0 to 4.2). It's using Canvas.clipPath() - a method which was implemented in software only up to Android 4.3. It means that you have to turn hardware acceleration off or your app will crash on not supported OpenGL call.

The best way to clip layouts is to use Canvas.saveLayer()/restoreLayer(). It's the only way to support all devices, get antialiased image and support invalidate/layout/draw flow correctly.

2.

Relying on timers and layout listeners to change layouts means that something is not really working for you. Each change can be executed directly without waiting. You just have to find the right place for that piece of code.

Timers can also trigger when your app is in background. It means that it will crash while trying to access UI from Timer thread.

Maybe you're calling setVisibility(true) somewhere in the code and that's why your FAB is visible? Setting visibility is ok and should work without any delayed calls. Just save visibility as FAB's state and restore it after orientation change.

If you wish to position the FAB at the center of the toolbar, wrap them both in a FrameLayout (wrap_content) and position the FAB with layout_gravity="center". That should allow you to remove layout listener.

3.

support.CardView is broken and shouldn't be used at all. It looks and works a little bit different on Lollipop and on older systems. The shadow is different, the padding is different, content clipping doesn't work on pre-Lollipop devices, etc. That's why it's hard to get consistent, good results on all platforms.

You should consider using plain layouts for that purpose.

4.

Some animations are cool-looking, but hard to implement, doesn't give any value and quickly become irritating, because the user has to wait for the animation to finish each time he/she clicks the button.

I'm not saying no for your case, but you may consider removing the transformation and using a drop down menu, a bottom sheet, a static toolbar or a dialog for that purpose.

Comment: Hi Zielony, thanks for your time. I'm start thinking you're right about removing this animation, especially because I'm not an expert about graphic things. I was using that library because it claimed to enable that effect in Android versions previous to Lollipop and I haven't readed nothing about hardware acceleration issues (or am I wrong again?).
I was using the CardView to show a little form to create a new entry in my database (just 2 edittexts). If I decide to replace CardView, what do you suggest me for that purpose? A DialogFragment (I use fragments)?

Comment: The hardware acceleration issue I'm talking about was reported as an issue here: https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal/issues/27 . I would use some kind of a dialog there, but I don't know your case and it's only my opinion. Pick what works best for you.

Comment: Thanks Zielony, I think I'll go for a DialogFragment.